# How to parse two elements from a list to make a new one

Tags: ruby

I have this input repeated in 1850 files:

```
[
    {
        "id"=>66939,
        "login"=>"XXX", 
        "url"=>"https://website.com/XX/users/XXX"
    },
    ... 
    {}
]
```

And I wanted to make a list in a way that by looking for the login I can retrieve the ID using a syntax like:

```
users_list[XXX]
```

This is my desired output:

```
{"XXX"=>"66570", "XXX"=>"66570", "XXX"=>"66570", "XXX"=>"66570", ... }
```

My code is:

```
i2 = 1
while i2 != users_list_raw.parsed.count
  temp_user = users_list_raw.parsed[i2]
  temp_user_login = temp_user['login']
  temp_user_id = temp_user['id']
  user = {
    temp_user_login => temp_user_id
  }
  users_list << user
  i2 += 1
end
```

My output is:

```
[{"XXX":66570},{"XXX":66569},{"XXX":66568},{"XXX":66567},{"XXX":66566}, ... {}]
```

but this is not what I want.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: If that’s not what you want then why are you putting them into an array? Put them in a hash.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this actually ^^, could you explain ? I'm googling right now

Comment: Instead of making `users_list` an array, make it  a Hash, and do : `users_list[temp_user_login] = temp_user_id`.

Comment: I hope you are not working with stolen login data, right? :-)

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek Uh oh...

Comment: Just kidding :-D

Comment: XD No i'm not, for the story, It's the data that I acquire thanks to my school's API !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hash[key] = value` to add an entry in a hash. So I guess in your case `users_list[temp_user_login] = temp_user_id`

But I'm unsure why you'd want to do that. I think you could look up the id of a user by having the login with a statement like:

```
login = XXX
user = users_list.select {|user| user["login"] == login}.first
id = user["id"]
```

and maybe put that in a function `get_id(login)` which takes the login as its parameter?

Also, you might want to look into databases if you're going to manipulate large amounts of data like this. ORMs (Object Relational Mappers) are available in Ruby such as Data Mapper and Active Record (which comes bundled with Rails), they allow you to "model" the data and create Ruby objects from data stored in a database, without writing SQL queries manually.

Comment: Oh yeah that's it ! Thanks !

Now i just have to make a single list out of my 1850 lists and it should work!

Comment: If you have thousands of entries in `user_list`, then this approach would be slow due to the linear lookup (`O(n)`) instead of constant (`O(1)`) for a hash structure.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek I did think about this, but I also thought creating the whole hash by iterating over each entry might not be worth it if there aren't that many lookups?

Comment: @Clepsyd: You are absolutely right. If there are not that many reads, then it really does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to lookup `users_list[XXX]` then a Hash would work well. We can construct that quite simply:

```
users_list = users_list_raw.parsed.each.with_object({}) do |user, list|
  list[user['login']] = user['id']
end
```

Any time you find yourself writing a `while` loop in Ruby, there might be a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep track of a mapping from keys to values, the best data structure is a hash. Be aware that assignment via the array operator will replace existing values in the hash.

```
login_to_id = {}

Dir.glob("*.txt") { |filename| # Use Dir.glob to find all files that you want to process

  data = eval(File.read(filename)) # Your data seems to be Ruby encoded hash/arrays. Eval is unsafe, I hope you know what you are doing.

  data.each { |hash|
    login_to_id[hash["login"]] = hash["id"]
  }
}

puts login_to_id["XXX"] # => 66939
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.